# Can't add y-intercept to linear model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I'm trying to build a multiple linear regression model using statsmodels. I want the model to include a constant, but it is not adding properly. I used a different, smaller dataset and it worked, my current one won't. My current data set is about 1000 observations x 2000 variables.

```
# Multiple Linear Regression

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Importing the dataset, y value is last column, other columns are X
dataset = pd.read_excel('sheet.xlsx')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1]
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1]

#Stats
X2 = sm.add_constant(X)
test = sm.OLS(y, X2)
test2 = test.fit()
print(test2.summary())
```

My output looks like this:

```
/home/chasel88/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py:1648: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  return 1 - (np.divide(self.nobs - self.k_constant, self.df_resid)
/home/chasel88/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py:1649: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  * (1 - self.rsquared))
/home/chasel88/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py:1665: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return self.ssr/self.df_resid
/home/chasel88/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py:1578: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return np.dot(wresid, wresid) / self.df_resid
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:            Reverse Log   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                    nan
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     0.000
Date:                 Di, 09 Jul 2019   Prob (F-statistic):                nan
Time:                        16:36:58   Log-Likelihood:                 31546.
No. Observations:                1097   AIC:                        -6.090e+04
Df Residuals:                       0   BIC:                        -5.541e+04
Df Model:                        1096                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Measurement1      2.1712        inf          0        nan         nan         nan
Measurement2    -0.1254        inf         -0        nan         nan         nan
Measurement3     -1.0199        inf         -0        nan         nan         nan
Measurement4      2.4232        inf          0        nan         nan         nan
Measurement5      0.7925        inf          0        nan         nan         nan
Measurement6     -0.6553        inf         -0        nan         nan         nan
```

It shows no y-intercept, but when I run this data in sklearn, I get an intercept. I'm only trying to use statsmodels so that I can get p values for my coefficients. In addition to the missing intercept, "nan" is written everywhere and it says there are divide by zero errors. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: You have 1097 observations, but 2000, seemingly non-collinear, variables. That perfect R-squared of 1 and 0 Df Residuals should be jumping out at you; you are severely overfitting your data.

Comment: I want to know which predictors are most influential in effecting my responding variable with a decent p-value. I don't need it to predict new data well. But I'm new at this, so I'm not sure if this is even the right direction at all.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to find which of my 2000 variables are most influential and significant. I'm not sure if this makes overfitting okay, but it's an aspect.

Comment: in that case you may want to look into a [LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) regression. It's one method of variable selection. This can be done with [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized.html) or [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html)

Answer (score 1):

It would help greatly to provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with both your `sklearn` and `statsmodels` regressions.

Setting aside the merits of running a regression with 2,000 variables, it seems that your input data may contain a column of constants. The help page for `sm.add_constant()` states:

> ```
> has_constant : str {'raise', 'add', 'skip'}
>     Behavior if ``data`` already has a constant. The default will return
>     data without adding another constant. If 'raise', will raise an
>     error if a constant is present. Using 'add' will duplicate the
>     constant, if one is present.
> ```

#### Normal behavior

```py
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':np.random.rand(20) // .1,
                  'x2':np.random.rand(20) // .01,
                  'x3':np.random.rand(20) // .01,
                  'y':np.random.rand(20) // .01})

X = df.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df.iloc[:, -1]

X2 = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X2).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

returns

```
const         23.7669     24.751      0.960      0.351     -28.702      76.236
x1             1.1993      2.943      0.408      0.689      -5.039       7.438
x2             0.4973      0.327      1.523      0.147      -0.195       1.190
x3            -0.1122      0.231     -0.486      0.634      -0.602       0.377
```

#### Constant already in data set

If there is already a constant term in the data set, `sm.add_constant()` runs, returns no message, and does not add a constant. In the example below, the constant is a value other than `1`, so the parameter for `k` in the regression output is different from the normal case above.

```py
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':np.random.rand(20) // .1,
                  'x2':np.random.rand(20) // .01,
                  'x3':np.random.rand(20) // .01,
                  'k':list([15])*20,
                  'y':np.random.rand(20) // .01})

X = df.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df.iloc[:, -1]

X2 = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X2).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

returns

```
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1             1.1993      2.943      0.408      0.689      -5.039       7.438
x2             0.4973      0.327      1.523      0.147      -0.195       1.190
x3            -0.1122      0.231     -0.486      0.634      -0.602       0.377
k              1.5845      1.650      0.960      0.351      -1.913       5.082
```

Comment: I used the has_constant='raise' argument and it raised an error and said that a constant was already present. Does this mean it is interpreting one of my columns as a constant? If there is already a constant, does it make sense that no constant is shown? Is there a way to ensure that none of the columns are used as a constant?

Comment: Actually, could my problem be that there are more variables than observations? When I use 800 ish variables compared to 1000 ish observations, it works, but not when I use 1200 ish variables or more.

Comment: @ChaseLewis Yes, if you already have a column where all values are identical, `sm.add_constant` will interpret *that column* as the constant, as in my example above. And as in the example, it won't display a parameter called `const`, but *will* display the constant column (in the second example above, `k`).

Comment: Especially given your testing with `has_constant='raise'`, I suspect that the column with constant values is one of the '400-ish' variables you did not include in the testing you describe in your second comment. You could test this with `df.nunique() == 1`

Comment: None of the columns have all identical values, although all columns are filled with 1 or 0. But I think it's when I add in the 1038th variable that the problem happens. Can I stop the program from choosing a column as a constant? Also, there is the issue of many of the stats turning to "nan" when there are more variable than my 1097 observations.

Comment: Regarding number of variables/columns `k` and observations/rows `N`, see [this answer from the stats Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135163/why-is-it-the-case-that-when-we-try-to-fit-an-ols-model-to-a-system-with-more-va) and [this medium.com post](https://medium.com/@jennifer.zzz/more-features-than-data-points-in-linear-regression-5bcabba6883e) for more information.